# is there a possible way to get a entrywise non negative matrix from an arbitrary matrix by matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices

I need to find a way to get a non negative matrix from an arbitrary matrix only by matrix multiplication,  something like: $Y$ is an arbitrary matrix, find matrices $M$(and $N$) $\neq 0 $  so that entries of matrix $ Q= M.Y$ or $Q =M.Y.N$ nonnegative

Comment: set M = 0 then you'll always get a nonnegative matrix

Comment: By "nonnegative", do you mean "entrywise nonnegative" or "nonnegative definite" (i.e. positive semidefinite)? Anyway, in either case, as Surb points out, set $M=0$ and you get a matrix that is both entrywise nonnegative and nonnegative definite.

Comment: i mean entrywise nonnegative

Answer (score 0):

This can always be done, e.g. by using [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

More generally, for any real or complex matrix $Y$, there always exist two invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $Y=PDQ$, where $D$ is a (possibly rectangular) diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries belong to $\{0,1\}$. Hence $P^{-1}YQ^{-1}$ is $D$, which is entrywise nonnegative.